# modifying a string variable

Tags: c#

I have a string variable which is named `query`.  It's value is:

> select col1, col2 from tab1
>   inner join (select col3, col4 from tab2)

Would it be possible to apply a treatment to this string variable to replace the first appearance of `select` with `select top 100`?

The string variable should become:

> select top 100 col1, col2 from tab1
>   inner join (select col3, col4 from tab2)

Comment: Take a look at the methods available on the string object.

Comment: What does the Description of the Post have to do with `Modifying` a `String` variable and then you have a `Sql Select Query` I am a bit lost with this question

Comment: @DJKRAZE - the question is simply asking to modify a string variable that contains a query to change the "select" portion to "select top 100".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = "select col1, col2 from tab1 inner join (select col3, col4 from tab2)";
var regex = new Regex("select");
query= regex.Replace(query, "Select TOP 100", 1);
```

This will make sure to only replace the first instance, instead of all instances of select.  It can also be easily modified if you need to change what you are replacing by changing the regex.

Comment: Bonus points if you use a case-insensitive expression

Answer (score 5):

```
query = "SELECT TOP 100 " + query.Substring("SELECT ".Length)
```

Comment: I'd add some kind of assertion to check that the string actually starts with "SELECT ".

Answer (score -2):

Or:

```
query = query.Replace("select col1", "select top 100 col1");
```

Comment: Doesn't work, there are two matches, but only the first should be replaced